# How to decode/encode ASCII_8BIT in the Scala?

Tags: ruby, scala, base64, ascii-8bit

I have an external system written in Ruby which sending a data over the wire encoded with `ASCII_8BIT`. How should I decode and encode them in the Scala?

I couldn't find a library for decoding and encoding `ASCII_8BIT` string in scala.

As I understand, correctly, the `ASCII_8BIT` is something similar to `Base64`. However, there is more than one `Base64` encoding. Which type of encoding should I use to be sure that cover all corner cases?

Comment: What have you tried? Code? Error?

Comment: I tried to decode via `akka.parboiled2.util.Base64.rfc2045` and it works. However, I don't know when it stops working, because it is not the same. Maybe it is the same but I don't know where to check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## What is ASCII-8BIT?

ASCII-8BIT is Ruby's binary encoding (the name "BINARY" is accepted as an alias for "ASCII-8BIT" when specifying the name of an encoding). It is used both for binary data and for text whose real encoding you don't know.

Any sequence of bytes is a valid string in the ASCII-8BIT encoding, but unlike other 8bit-encodings, only the bytes in the ASCII range are considered printable characters (and of course only those that are printable in ASCII). The bytes in the 128-255 range are considered special characters that don't have a representation in other encodings. So trying to convert an ASCII-8BIT string to any other encoding will fail (or replace the non-ASCII characters with question marks depending on the options you give to `encode`) unless it only contains ASCII characters.

## What's its equivalent in the Scala/JVM world?

There is no strict equivalent. If you're dealing with binary data, you should be using binary streams that don't have an encoding and aren't treated as containing text.

If you're dealing with text, you'll either need to know (or somehow figure out) its encoding or just arbitrarily pick an 8-bit ASCII-superset encoding. That way non-ASCII characters may come out as the wrong character (if the text was actually encoded with a different encoding), but you won't get any errors because any byte is a valid character. You can then replace the non-ASCII characters with question marks if you want.

## What does this have to do with Base64?

Nothing. Base64 is a way to represent binary data as ASCII text. It is not itself a character encoding. Knowing that a string has the character encoding ASCII or ASCII-8BIT or any other encoding, doesn't tell you whether it contains Base64 data or not.

But do note that a Base64 string will consist entirely of ASCII characters (and not just any ASCII characters, but only letters, numbers, `+`, `/`  and `=`). So if your string contains any non-ASCII character or any character except the aforementioned, it's not Base64.

Therefore any Base64 string can be represented as ASCII. So if you have an ASCII-8BIT string containing Base64 data in Ruby, you should be able to convert it to ASCII without any problems. If you can't, it's not Base64.